# Application with sharedUserId kills other apps with the same uid when installed

Tags: android, process, installation, kill, userid

I have two applications, let's call them APP-A and APP-B, they share the userid `"com.example.app.USER"`, if APP-A is running and I install APP-B, APP-A closes.
Does anyone know if this behavior is intended? 
If it is, could you link to any reference in the documentation?
If not, what can I do as a workaround?

---

**EDIT:**

Just a note: this happens when APP-B is installed via `adb install`, if installed from the device's file browser the proccess is killed then restarted. (This is very frustrating as this bypasses exception handling via `try...catch` blocks)

Comment: Why are you using `sharedUserId`? Why not use a cleaner API between the apps, secured by a signature-level custom permission?

Comment: APP-B copies images over to the internal storage and shares their path with APP-A wich in turn can only access APP-B's sandbox if they share the same user id. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Have APP-B implement a `ContentProvider`. Have APP-A access the images via the `ContentProvider`. Use a signature-level custom permission to ensure that only APP-A (or any future app that you write) can use APP-B's `ContentProvider`. With this, you do not need to mess around with `sharedUserId`, and APP-A is not as dependent upon APP-B's implementation (e.g., APP-B can reorganize its directory structure but maintain a consistent `Uri` structure to insulate APP-A from those changes).

Comment: Sadly I cannot alter the application in such way, I reconize it is a good solution however i must not discontinue the use of the `sharedUserId`. The behavior I cited is not nocive to the app but it is being considered a bug and I should provide information justify wether or not this is fixable.

Comment: You can't stop Android from doing what it's doing during installation since that [is very central to the platform's security](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#L163). IDK if it is technically necessary to kill other apps of the same id but it's not unlikely that not doing so could result in errors and inconsistent states.